# SonarLint is unable to analyze file (Null Pointer Exception) with StringBuffer

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

SonarLint 2.2.1 is unable to analyze the following Java class in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2

```
public class Temp {
    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface IX {
        void execute(StringBuffer sb);
    }
    static {
        x(sb -> y());
    }
    private static void x(IX parm) {}
    private static void y(){}
}
```

If I change StringBuffer to anything else then there is no problem.

ADDITIONAL NOTE: Replacing StringBuffer with Stack<Object> also causes the problem.

Here is the dump that I see

```
    Error during analysis
    org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'C:\projects\...\Temp.java'
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:93)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:87)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:52)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:73)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:63)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:44)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.analysis.AnalysisContainer.doAfterStart(AnalysisContainer.java:143)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:110)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.StandaloneGlobalContainer.analyze(StandaloneGlobalContainer.java:118)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.java:93)
        at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.java:83)
        at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.java:60)
        at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob.run(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:463)
        at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob$AnalysisThread.run(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:127)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonar.java.AnalyzerMessage.textSpanBetween(AnalyzerMessage.java:122)
        at org.sonar.java.AnalyzerMessage.textSpanFor(AnalyzerMessage.java:111)
        at org.sonar.java.model.DefaultJavaFileScannerContext.createAnalyzerMessage(DefaultJavaFileScannerContext.java:133)
        at org.sonar.java.model.DefaultJavaFileScannerContext.reportIssue(DefaultJavaFileScannerContext.java:118)
        at org.sonar.java.model.DefaultJavaFileScannerContext.reportIssue(DefaultJavaFileScannerContext.java:113)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.IssuableSubscriptionVisitor.reportIssue(IssuableSubscriptionVisitor.java:57)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.SynchronizedClassUsageCheck$DeprecatedTypeVisitor.reportIssueOnDeprecatedType(SynchronizedClassUsageCheck.java:102)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.SynchronizedClassUsageCheck$DeprecatedTypeVisitor.visitVariable(SynchronizedClassUsageCheck.java:95)
        at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.VariableTreeImpl.accept(VariableTreeImpl.java:184)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitLambdaExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:342)
        at org.sonar.java.model.expression.LambdaExpressionTreeImpl.accept(LambdaExpressionTreeImpl.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.parser.ListTreeImpl.accept(ListTreeImpl.java:63)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:48)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(BaseTreeVisitor.java:252)
        at org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl.accept(MethodInvocationTreeImpl.java:96)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitExpressionStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:101)
        at org.sonar.java.model.statement.ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.accept(ExpressionStatementTreeImpl.java:65)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.SynchronizedClassUsageCheck$DeprecatedTypeVisitor.visitClass(SynchronizedClassUsageCheck.java:73)
        at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:198)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
        at org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$CompilationUnitTreeImpl.accept(JavaTree.java:184)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.SynchronizedClassUsageCheck.visitNode(SynchronizedClassUsageCheck.java:61)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're facing the following bug in the Java analyzer which is going to be fixed in the upcoming 4.3 version of the Java analyzer and so as well of the upcoming version of SonarLint for Eclipse : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1838